# 'tail -f' does not follow when file updated using 'tee'

Tags: linux, bash, sh

I listen to stream like this:

```
cat /dev/ttyS4 | tee -a mylog.log
```

This correctly outputs data to mylog.log as well as to the terminal.
I try to follow the file in another terminal:

```
tail -f mylog.log
```

This does not sense an update.
If i run ls -la (to see the date of the file), the tail output gets updated. (I can also run 'touch myfile.log'

A couple of years since Linux was my main environment, but I think that this should work without forcing some time update with touch.

I use Ubuntu for Windows.

Comment: Could it be buffering of the writes? If you wait a bit longer (until more data is written from `cat` to the pipe to `tee`), does it show up in `tail` then?

Comment: `I use Ubuntu for Windows.` I do not know how this would affect (buffered) writing to files. [the windows filesystem differs from a inode-based filesystem, too]

Comment: Are you on WSL 1 or 2? I’ve had issues with filesystem being completely out of date between different WSL1 instances, and between Windows and WSL. Including edit file in one instance, or in Windows, the other instance still has the old file. Although Windows is always up to date with changes from WSL.

Comment: @wildplasser WSL doesn't use a "windows filessystem". It's a virtual machine with its own file system. (The file system within is exposed, but only through communication with a program within the VM.)

Comment: What happens if you to a `stdbuf -i0 -o0 -e0 tee -a mylog.log </dev/ttyS4` instead, thereby turning off buffering in _tee_ and removing the unnecessary `cat`?

Answer (score 2):

You should use `tail -F` (sighs I know ...) as it will detect if the file have been renamed, rotated, etc and if so, open a new file describer for the "new" file.

See `man tail`:

```
$ $ man tail | awk '/-F/' RS= 
SYNOPSIS
     tail [-F | -f | -r] [-q] [-b number | -c number | -n number] [file ...]
     -F      The -F option implies the -f option, but tail will also check to
             see if the file being followed has been renamed or rotated.  The
             file is closed and reopened when tail detects that the filename
             being read from has a new inode number.  The -F option is ignored
             if reading from standard input rather than a file.
STANDARDS
     The tail utility is expected to be a superset of the IEEE Std 1003.2-1992
     (``POSIX.2'') specification.  In particular, the -F, -b and -r options
     are extensions to that standard.
```

Comment: Why do you think the used `tee -a mylog.log` causes `mylog.log` being _renamed, rotated, etc_?

Comment: I think I assumed that you ran `tail` first and then later ran the `tee` command. But it seems like I was wrong?

Comment: It wasn't me running that, but apart from that I think you're right thinking you were wrong. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

`tail`, when not writing to a terminal but a pipe or a file, will buffer its output blockwise. Meaning it will output text into the pipe not before the buffer reached a certain size. This buffering is implemented in the gnu libc, see the link below.

On Linux, you can adjust the buffer size and the buffering behaviour at all using the [`stdbuf`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/stdbuf) command. The following command for example will make tail output line by line:

```
stdbuf -oL tail ... | tee ...
```

- https://linux.die.net/man/1/stdbuf
- https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Controlling-Buffering.html

Answer (score 0):

Update: `tail -F` does not work. The file is not rotated and `ls -la` (or touch) on the file would lead to the `tail -f` working.

I actually resorted to this hack. Just call `ls -la` continuously to trigger the system to sense that it has changed. Like this:

```
while true; do ls -la; sleep 1; done
```

It is a hack, but it works for me. So it does not actually solve the observed behavior. I think this is a "Linux on windows" problem and not a Linux problem, so I will not spend more time on this issue.